# Calculation of current density distribution in ferromagnetic strip with barber-pole geometry

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

I'm working on a mathematical model of an AMR sensor, the basis of which is a current-carrying thin ferromagnetic film with highly conductive strips placed at a 45° angle on top of the film:

[image]

The conductivity of these strips is about an order of magnitude higher than that of the film, therefore, they act as a shunt, changing the inclination of the current in the plane of the film (for simplicity, we can assume that the conductivity of both materials is known and stays constant, but not necessarily isotropic).

I need to calculate the path the current will take when these strips are present.

I can do this by calculating the electrostatic potential:

∇ ⋅ ( σ ∇ V) = 0,‎ ‎ (1)

which is derived from:

**E** = - ∇ V, (2)

**j** = σ **E**, (3)

∇ ⋅ **j** = 0 (for the electrostatic case). (4)

After getting the electrostatic potential from (1), I can calculate the electric field from (2), after which I can find the current density distribution via (3).

I have applied this method to a finite-element geometry that consists of a number of points in 3d space, separated by a set distance h on all axes. The points are denoted by their indices {i, j, k}

By expanding equation (1), and using the finite difference approximations for the first and second order partial derivatives, I can express the electrostatic potential at a given point as:

V{i, j, k} = 1/6 * 1/σ{i, j, k} * ( σ{i+1, j, k} - σ{i-1, j, k} )*( V{i+1, j, k} - V{i-1, j, k} ) / 4h²   +   σ{i, j, k} * (V{i+1, j, k} + V{i-1, j, k})/h² + ... (repeated twice, shifting the indices every time) ).

I also applied boundary conditions to the current and potential - at the boundary faces the the normal component of **j** must be equal to zero to avoid current leakage, and V at the contact points on the opposite ends of the film is fixed.

However, the calculation results were not quite what was expected. Instead of following a zigzag pattern, the current seems to prefer a straight path, with higher density at the low-resistance conductive strips:

[image]

Does anyone know why this could be happening? Maybe there is something I didn't account for?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps, I should have added a boundary condition for the electric field at the boundary between the ferromagnetic and conductive material? Could this be why the equation is not applicable in it's current form?